# how to sum or join the values of 2 or more different dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to know how to sum or join the value from 2 dicts in the following code.

```
#Read JSON file and assign it to the variable.
sentimentos = pd.read_json('/content/sample_data/words_sentiment.json')

#convert the variable into a dictionary.
sentiment_dict = sentimentos.to_dict('dict')

#funcao get_sentiment gets 2 arguments.
#1) A list of string/substring
#2) A dictionary with a value for each word.
#3) For each string it verifies if it exists on the dictionary.

def get_sentiment(token, words_sentiment):
  for word in token:
    if (word in words_sentiment):
      print(words_sentiment[word])
    else:
      print("Sorry. We couldn't find that word.")


get_sentiment(["im", "mad", "as", "hell"], sentiment_dict)
```

the outcome is :

```
Sorry. We couldn't find that word.
{'anger': 1, 'anticipation': 0, 'disgust': 1, 'fear': 1, 'joy': 0, 'negative': 1, 'positive': 0, 'sadness': 1, 'surprise': 0, 'trust': 0}
Sorry. We couldn't find that word.
{'anger': 1, 'anticipation': 0, 'disgust': 1, 'fear': 1, 'joy': 0, 'negative': 1, 'positive': 0, 'sadness': 1, 'surprise': 0, 'trust': 0}
```

I want to know how I can sum those values I got and return this at the end of the function :

```
{'anger': 2, 'anticipation': 0, 'disgust': 2, 'fear': 2, 'joy': 0, 'negative': 2, 'positive': 0, 'sadness': 2, 'surprise': 0, 'trust': 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

The following function will take two dictionaries and add them together

```
    def add_two_dicts(dict1, dict2):
        output = {}

        for key in dict1:
            if key in output:
                output[key] += dict1[key]
            else:
                output[key] = dict1[key]

        for key in dict2:
            if key in output:
                output[key] += dict2[key]
            else:
                output[key] = dict2[key]

        return output



    dict1 = {'anger': 1, 'anticipation': 0, 'disgust': 1, 'fear': 1, 'joy': 0, 'negative': 1, 'positive': 0, 'sadness': 1, 'surprise': 0, 'trust': 0}
    dict2 = {'anger': 1, 'anticipation': 0, 'disgust': 1, 'fear': 1, 'joy': 0, 'negative': 1, 'positive': 0, 'sadness': 1, 'surprise': 0, 'trust': 0}

    print(add_two_dicts(dict1, dict2))
```

which will output the following:

```
{'anger': 2, 'anticipation': 0, 'disgust': 2, 'fear': 2, 'joy': 0, 'negative': 2, 'positive': 0, 'sadness': 2, 'surprise': 0, 'trust': 0}
```